# How to handle Null array in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq

I have a methods that takes multiple arrays and filter data using linq, the problem I am having is that one or more arrays could be null and I am not sure how to handle null arrays in Linq.:

```
public IPagedList<SGProduct> GetFilteredProducts(string catID, string[] houseID, int page = 1)
        {
            return MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>().AsEnumerable().Where(x =>houseID.Contains(x.HouseID.ToString()) && x.ProductCategoryID.ToString() == catID).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 6);
        }
```

The houseID array could be null also I will have more parameters to this method like Size array etc.

Any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add null check for array, end create empty one if it's null.

```
public IPagedList<SGProduct> GetFilteredProducts(string catID, string[] houseID, int page = 1)
{
    if(houseID == null) houseID = new string[] {};
    return MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>().AsEnumerable().Where(x =>houseID.Contains(x.HouseID.ToString()) && x.ProductCategoryID.ToString() == catID).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 6);
}
```

Also, you can `query` variable and build it with conditions as you go. And then you have finished, just materialize and return records.

```
public IPagedList<SGProduct> GetFilteredProducts(string catID, string[] houseID, int page = 1)
{
    var query = MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>();
    if(houseID == null)
        query = query.Where(x =>houseID.Contains(x.HouseID.ToString()) && x.ProductCategoryID.ToString() == catID);

    return query.ToList().ToPagedList(page, 6);
}
```